# Syntax Preprocessors for Java

Tags: java, macros, dsl, dsl-tools

I'm looking for a Java macro language that provides for convenient ways of doing closures (that compile to anonymous inner classes) and list comprehension (that compiles down to basic java loops).

An example of the kind of thing I'm looking for would be Xtend2 http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/#xtend2

But I want something for general purpose programming (Xtend2 is very specific DSL for Xtext and has a ton of dependencies). Maybe even something that would let me define multiple classes in a single file (which would then get split up into two separate files by the pre-processor).

Does anything like this exist?

Edited to add:
I'm doing Android development so any alternatives have to generate either valid Java source or the byte code has to be compatible with the dalvik recompiler.

Comment: Any reason you do not just use language with the features you need.  Clojure would probably be a good bet.

Comment: I'm doing Android development so the output has to be Java source or something the dalvik compiler can crunch. As far as I know Clojure doesn't work on Android.

Comment: Can the byte code generated by Fantom be re-compiled by the dalvik compiler?

Comment: Xtend has one of the least runtime dependencies of any JVM-language out there. It's really only a couple of classes decorating the Java SDK. And I don't understand why you think Xtend is specific to Xtext? It's just implemented with it.

Comment: It's been a few years since my question and I think the best solution today to my original problem is to switch to C# and use MonoDroid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mmm, there used to be the [JSE](http://jse.sourceforge.net/), which was tremendous fun, back in the day.

Mirah is cool, but not ready for primetime, IMO.

You can do a lot with smart templating, although your source view is the Java.

There's a post on SO about using XTend on Android from a few days ago, too.

Answer (score 0):

[Frege](http://code.google.com/p/frege) produces java source code.

I do not know whether dalvik would like it. (But I would be interested to hear ...)
And, of course, you have some runtime library code.

That being said, there are a number of other projects that do closures etc. in java, for example: [lambdaj](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/)